# How can I update my bash profile to include an alias?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make an alias in my bash profile, for example having python always execute python3 and other text replacements like that. How can this be done on mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you're in the bash profile...

```
nano .bash_profile
```

you can add an alias like this...

```
alias l='ls -lah'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nano .bash_profile
```

That's probably the simplest way to get in to your bash profile on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias python='python3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step by step walk through: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/make-an-alias-in-bash-shell-in-os-x-terminal/

Answer (score 1):

There is (or should be) a file called .bash_profile where your terminal fires up. Open it in a text editor, and enter something like

alias desktop="cd c:/users/michael/desktop"

This particular one takes me to the desktop in the terminal when I enter 'desktop'

Answer (score 1):

If you create an alias for python, you should also consider creating an alias for pip.

```
alias pip='pip3'
```

Not required but will probably help you avoid problems/errors in the future.